# Rendering Text using openGL by updating VBO

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am trying to render Text using opengl. I have the fonts loaded into a texture properly and I have the UV coordinates per letter correct. When I try updating my already existing VBO to fit the text I want to draw, nothing happens. I can draw the entire texture or a single character using another Image object I created beforehand so I know the UV and  Texture are correct.

I have tried reorganizing my opengl calls, using a different input system for my shaders, and basically copying my working Image code but nothing worked. The only different thing I have is that I am using glBufferSubData to update the vbo with the correct coordinates to draw each letter. I am thinking this is my problem since I am not too proficient with that method of opengl rendering.

Init

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < LINE_LENGTH; i++) {
    addPoint(x, y, 0.0, 1.0);//x0
    addPoint(x, y, 0.0, 0.0);//x0
    addPoint(x, y, 1.0, 0.0);//x1
    addPoint(x, y, 0.0, 1.0);//x0
    addPoint(x, y, 1.0, 0.0);//x1
    addPoint(x, y, 1.0, 1.0);//x1
}

glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(float)*LINE_LENGTH*24,&vert[0],GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(float)*4,(void*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(float)*4,(void*)(sizeof(float)*2));

//Unbind
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Render

```cpp
//*LOOP TO UPDATE VALUES NOT SHOWN, TESTED AND IS CORRECT*//

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

Shader* s = Shader::useShader(CompiledWebWindow::TEXT_SHADER);
glm::vec3 color(1,0,0);
s->setVec3("textColor",color);
s->setMat4("projection",*(GLWin::getProjection()));
s->setInt("ourTexture",0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureId);

//Update data
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,sizeof(float)*end*24,&vert[0]);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,end*6);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(1); 
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0); 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Vertex Shader

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos; // <vec2 pos, vec2 tex>
layout (location = 1) in vec2 UV; // <vec2 pos, vec2 tex>

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = UV;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
uniform vec3 textColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(ourTexture, TexCoord).r);
    FragColor = vec4(textColor, 1.0) * sampled;
}
```

I am expecting some text to be drawn but am left with a blank screen.

Comment: When you set up the array of vertex coordinates, then all the coordinates are the same, it is always `addPoint(x, y, ...)`.

Comment: I later on change the array inside the render loop to the correct x y u v.

Comment: Yea but each item has 6 triangles with 4 elements each so that’s why it is 24. Also why did you suggest subtracting line length

Comment: I never suggested to subtract any length. Is `end` == `LINE_LENGTH`?

Comment: Line length is a constant to specify max chars per line and end is how many letters we draw.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find any obvious issue in this code. What is the projection matrix?

Comment: I am using an orthogonal projection, it’s making the view act like most screen graphics, origin is top left and it’s per pixel kind of deal.